# Cannot Find Symbol errors everywhere

Tags: java, swing, button, user-interface, compiler-errors

This is supposed to a three part panel with the top panel being a label that is updated with a number when a button in the middle panel is pressed. The label is cleared when a 
clear button on the bottom is pressed.

The Problem is that almost every mention of each button from the middle panel causes a "cannot find symbol" error...

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NumericKeypadPanel2 extends JPanel
{


//----------------------------------------------------------------------


    public NumericKeypadPanel2()
    {
        JButton b1 = new JButton ("1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton ("2");
        JButton b3 = new JButton ("3");
        JButton b4 = new JButton ("4");
        JButton b5 = new JButton ("5");
        JButton b6 = new JButton ("6");
        JButton b7 = new JButton ("7");
        JButton b8 = new JButton ("8");
        JButton b9 = new JButton ("9");
        JButton b10 = new JButton ("*");
        JButton b11 = new JButton ("0");
        JButton b12 = new JButton ("#");
        JButton clear = new JButton ("Clear");

        NumListener listener = new NumListener();

        b1.addActionListener (listener);
        b2.addActionListener (listener);
        b3.addActionListener (listener);
        b4.addActionListener (listener);
        b5.addActionListener (listener);
        b6.addActionListener (listener);
        b7.addActionListener (listener);
        b8.addActionListener (listener);
        b9.addActionListener (listener);
        b10.addActionListener (listener);
        b11.addActionListener (listener);
        b12.addActionListener (listener);
        clear.addActionListener (listener);

        String num = " ";

        JPanel panel_main = new JPanel();
        panel_main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //top
        JLabel display = new JLabel(num);
        display.setBorder (BorderFactory.createLineBorder (Color.black, 3));
        panel_main.add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //mid
        JPanel keypad = new JPanel();
        keypad.setLayout(new GridLayout (4, 3));
        keypad.setBorder (BorderFactory.createLineBorder (Color.black, 3));
        //adding the buttons
        keypad.add (b1);
        keypad.add (b2);
        keypad.add (b3);
        keypad.add (b4);
        keypad.add (b5);
        keypad.add (b6);
        keypad.add (b7);
        keypad.add (b8);
        keypad.add (b9);
        keypad.add (b10);
        keypad.add (b11);
        keypad.add (b12);
        //adding the panel
        panel_main.add(keypad, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //btm
        panel_main.add(clear, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    private class NumListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource() == b1)
            {
                display.setText(display.getText()+"1");
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == b2)
            {
                display.setText(display.getText()+"2");
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == b3)
            {
                display.setText(display.getText()+"3");
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == b4)
            {
                display.setText(display.getText()+"4");
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == b5)
            {
                display.setText(display.getText()+"5");
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == b6)
            {
                display.setText(display.getText()+"6");
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == b7)
            {
                display.setText(display.getText()+"7");
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == b8)
            {
                display.setText(display.getText()+"8");
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == b9)
            {
                display.setText(display.getText()+"9");
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == b10)
            {
                display.setText(display.getText()+"*");
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == b11)
            {
                display.setText(display.getText()+"0");
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == b12)
            {
                display.setText(display.getText()+"#");
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == clear)
            {
                display.setText(" ");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *"The Problem is that almost every mention of each button.."*  You should have found this out after one or two buttons, not 10+.  Compile often for lower stress!

Answer (score 2):

All of your `JButtons` and `JLabels` are declared as local variables in your constructor, so they aren't accessible from outside the constructor.

To have them available to other methods, declare those variables as instance variables in your class (outside of any methods or constructors).  Then they'll be in scope for the entire class.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with rgettman.Here is just code sample:

```
public class NumericKeypadPanel2 extends JPanel 
{
    private JButton b1 = new JButton ("1");
    private JButton b2 = new JButton ("2");
    private JButton b3 = new JButton ("3");
    private JButton b4 = new JButton ("4");
    private JButton b5 = new JButton ("5");
    private JButton b6 = new JButton ("6");
    private JButton b7 = new JButton ("7");
    private JButton b8 = new JButton ("8");
    private JButton b9 = new JButton ("9");
    private JButton b10 = new JButton ("*");
    private JButton b11 = new JButton ("0");
    private JButton b12 = new JButton ("#");
    private JButton clear = new JButton ("Clear");

    private  JLabel display = new JLabel();


    public NumericKeypadPanel2() 
    {

        NumListener listener = new NumListener();

        b1.addActionListener (listener);
        b2.addActionListener (listener);
        b3.addActionListener (listener);
        b4.addActionListener (listener);
        b5.addActionListener (listener);
        b6.addActionListener (listener);
        b7.addActionListener (listener);
        b8.addActionListener (listener);
        b9.addActionListener (listener);

        // .....
    }

}
```